# Android: BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I am trying to listen to the phone state when contact is calling me but i am getting some error.

ServiceReceiver.java

```
package org.example.servicereceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;


public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "ServiceReceiver"; 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener=new MyPhoneStateListener();
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Log.d(TAG, "telephony: " + telephony);

        telephony.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

MyPhoneStateListener.java

```
package org.example.servicereceiver;

import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){
        switch(state)
        {
           case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
                break;
           case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
                break;
           case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
               Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
               break;
        }
    }   

}
```

Errors:

```
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.example.servicereceiver/org.example.servicereceiver.ServiceReceiver}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.example.servicereceiver.ServiceReceiver
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2709)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.example.servicereceiver.ServiceReceiver
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1036)
04-13 18:25:21.845: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2701)
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.example.servicereceiver"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".ServiceReceiver"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I added to AndroidManifest.xml premission READ_PHONE_STATE and registred reciever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<activity android:name=".ServiceReceiver"
```

I'd say the above is what's causing the problem - get rid of the entry for the activity and just leave the `<receiver>` section.

Comment: Sorry, what do you think? I am just learning english and i totally don't understand what did you mean.I must delete this?

Comment: @Husky: Yes - delete the <activity></activity> section in the AndroidManifest.xml. Android is trying to 'launch' your receiver as an activity. You cannot 'launch' a receiver - it will be registered by the system when you install the app and started when the phone state changes.

Comment: @Husky: Sorry my answer had the word <receiver> missing - I've edited it.

Comment: If i delete it, i can't run my app.It wrote aplication isn't instaled on my device when i clicked on that icon.

Comment: @Husky: Do you have an Activity class in your app?

Comment: @Husky: If you don't have an Activity, you won't be able to 'start' anything that you can see. Only an Activity has a UI (user interface). It is possible to have an app which only has a BroadcastReceiver. When you install it, the BroadcastReceiver is 'registered' by the applications manager from information in <receiver></receiver> section. It will be started automatically by Android when the phone state changes (when the PHONE_STATE Intent is broadcast).

Comment: @Husky: Good to hear. Glad to help.