# Android BroadcastRecevier for App Permissions

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

How would you create a broadcast receiver for when there is a change in your app's permissions?

Comment: broadcast receiver do not  need Permission

Comment: Why do you need to listen for a change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: BroadcastReceiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652472/android-broadcastreceiver)

Comment: No I did not know that the application was restarted on app permission change. I thought that a user could be in the app and then change permission without the app realizing what changes took place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a BroadcastReceiver for App permissions since there is no broadcast. As soon as there is a permission change, the app is restarted.

EDIT: You can check for permissions yourselves by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17994076/6570665).

Comment: Thanks! I know how to check for permissions, but I did not know that the app was restarted on permission change!